# Stuck in login loop when connected to motherboard HDMI

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, gpu-driver

**Problem**

I'm running Ubuntu on a new computer that has 2 HDMI ports. One provided by a dedicated graphics card and the other from the motherboard. When the graphics card is driving the HDMI output the computer works great. I want to keep this graphics card free for processing so Im trying to work with the other HDMI port. When I use the motherboard HDMI port the display resolution i very low and I am not able to login. Ubuntu starts to load and then returns back to the login screen and I am stuck in that loop.

**System Description**

- OS: Ubuntu 16
- Motherboard: ASUA TUF Z370 Pro Gaming LGA1151
- Power Supply: Corsair CS Series 850 Watt
- CPU: Intel 8th Gen Core i7-8700K
- GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080 Ti Founders Edition
- GPU-Driver: nvidia-390
  Memory: Corsair LPX 32GB (2x16GB) 3200MHz C16 DDR4 DRAM
  Storage: Corsair Force Series MP500 24GB M.2 NVMe

**Attempted Solutions**

- reinstalling lightdm
- reinstalling nvidia drivers
- permissions/backups for `~/.Xauthority`
- reinstalling Ubuntu

Comment: First, you need to make sure BIOS allows to use both cards. It seems you have done that. Is look like XServers crashes when it starts on your login. I had problems with nvidia drivers running alongside other graphic adapters. If I used nouveau driver for nvidia, it worked for me and I was able to use onboard Intel with nvidia.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `dmesg` output and `/var/log/xorg.0.log`. This will give you valuable information about what is going wrong.

I think in your case the integrated graphics card (UHD Graphics 630) is simply not yet supported.

It seems you need at least kernel 4.13 and mesa 17.2. Just look at this [phoronix](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=coffee-uhd-graphics&num=1) article for details. Even in 17.10 the support is not marked as stable.

If you want to use newer mesa and kernel with 16.04, you will have to get those over ppas, e.g. the [oibaf ppa](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers) for mesa and graphics drivers.

I would probably suggest to wait another month for 18.04